# Parabola equation (sign of coefficients)

Tags: functions

Consider the equation
$$
y=a^2x +bx
$$

Which signs of $a,b$ can deliver the picture below? I suspect that I need $a>0$ and $b<0$ with $|b|$ larger enough than $a$. Is that correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. If $y=ax^2+bx$, then $(0,0)$ belongs to the parabola. So, you will not get a graph like that picture.

Comment: I think he is asking about curvature(upwards) as well

Comment: I suppose so, but nevertheles what I did shows that the graph will never be that picture.